# Can I transfer my Windows 10 over to Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, user-data

I have been thinking of trading windows for Linux for a long time now. What stops me is being a hoarder. I don't want to lose all the stuff on my windows.

Can Ubuntu transfer everything in my user account, data and programs, over to itself?

Comment: Short answer: No, you can't. Windows programs won't run in Ubuntu.

Comment: I know programs won't run. I'm asking about the stuff on my desktop and the various MY folders. Then I can check and see if there are linux versions for each. My memory is horrible. I will forget some, even important stuff, if I don't have it.

Comment: The best way is to copy your files somwhere else, install Ubuntu, then copy your files back. Ubuntu has different filesystems. If you leave an NTFS partitition without Windows installed, it will cause troubles later.